# Html table indent problem

Tags: html, css

I have this form:

[image]

Markup is:

```
<table style="width: 100%; padding:5px;">
<col style="width: 20%; text-align: left" />
<col style="width: 80%; text-align: left" />
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            Наименование</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <dx:ASPxButtonEdit ID="beWorkTypeName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False">
            <Buttons>
                <dx:EditButton>
                </dx:EditButton>
            </Buttons>
        </dx:ASPxButtonEdit>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            Скважина</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <dx:ASPxButtonEdit ID="beWell" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False">
            <Buttons>
                <dx:EditButton>
                </dx:EditButton>
            </Buttons>
        </dx:ASPxButtonEdit>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            Дата начала</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="deBeginDate" runat="server">
                    </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnDateChange" AutoPostBack="false" Enabled="false" Text="Изменить дату"
                        runat="server">
                    </dx:ASPxButton>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="cbIsMainWorkType" Enabled="false" runat="server">
                    </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        Основной вид работ в заявке</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Question is:
How do I get rid of this awful indent of table inside another table?

Comment: your css code and even a jsbin.com live example would help us

Comment: I have only a runtime-formed CSS, from Devexpress controls. All other css is here (don't ask why it's implemented in every tag and not in file, please). AND: Intuition says that problem is not in Devexpress's CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to style your inner table as follows:

```
.innerTable {
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**EDIT:** You also might need to remove spacing from the table rows and cells:

```
.innerTable tr {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.innerTable th {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.innerTable td {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Indent has lessened, now it's very small, nearly 1px in size. But it's still there. Maybe one more CSS attribute, please? :)

Comment: Maybe you need to also style the table rows and cells. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to layout form elements using CSS without using tables - hopefully it'll help?  The key is in setting the width on the label elements, which then makes the input controls to their right lineup.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
label {
float: left;
width: 10em;
margin-right: 1em;
}

.row {
float: left;
clear: left;
padding-bottom: .3em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="example.php">
<div class="row">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input id="name" name="name" class="text" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="email">Email address:</label>
<input id="email" name="email" class="text" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="phone">Telephone:</label>
<input id="phone" name="phone" class="text" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="row">
<input class="submit" type="submit"
value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```